# BSoD During Windows 10 Factory USB install, attempted write to read only memory (WimFsf.sys)

Tags: windows-10, usb, installation, bsod

I purchased a Windows 10 Home Edition OEM USB Installation kit (factory USB-based install).  During the "Enter your license key" step of the install a blue screen of death (BSoD) is displayed and a page access fault is described as the culprit.

`Attempted write to read only memory (WimFsf.sys)`

This is a brand new build with top-end hardware (ASUS board, i7 GPU, ASUS GPU, Crucial memory, Samsung SSD). I have tried numerous bios tweaks, swapped the SSD, removed one of the sticks of RAM (thinking it might be RAM related) all to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was something to do with the FACTORY USB thumb drive.  To get past this I ended up using Microsoft's tool for building a Windows 10 installation USB thumb drive and it worked like a charm.

As much as I did not want to believe it was the USB drive... it was the darn USB drive! :(